# Cypress - Click on an element only if it is clickable

Tags: click, cypress, paginator

Is there a method in Cypress to simulate the paginator functionality of a webpage?

An example scenario for this would be the paginator functionality of a webpage.
So this function or method would enable me to click on the 'next page' or 'previous page' icons until I can go no further.

An example of what code I am requesting information on would be:

```
while (cy.get(<locator string>).isClickable()) {
     cy.get(<locator string>).click();
     //and some other instructions to follow;
}
```

Hope I was able to portray it correctly! ;)

Comment: Do you need to wait and retry till the button is enabled OR you just directly need to check whether the button is enabled ot disabled and make the `click()` ?

Comment: You got it right on the second time - I just need to check if the button is enabled and make the click().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop part can be handled with a recursive function,

```js
function clickUntilDisabled(selector, callback, pageNo = 0) {

  if (pageNo === 100) {
    throw 'Too many clicks'                          // avoid runaway recursive calls
  }

  cy.get(selector).then($clickable => {
    if ($clickable.prop('disabled')) return;         // exit

    $clickable.click()
    callback(pageNo)                                 // other stuff to do
    clickUntilDisabled(selector, callback, ++pageNo) // repeat
  })
}

clickUntilDisabled('my-button', (pageNo) => {
  cy.get('row').should(...);                         // testing page here
})
```

---

#### Proof of concept

**Example app**

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="nextpage()">Next Page</button>
  <p>Page no: _</p>

  <script>
    let count = -1
    function nextpage() {

      count++
      console.log('Click handler nextpage', count)

      setTimeout(() => {                           // some async change
        const p = document.querySelector('p')      // to make sure the loop 
        p.innerText = `Page no: ${count}`          // waits for fetch
      }, 2000)

      if (count < 3) return  

      // disable after 3rd click
      const button = document.querySelector('button')
      button.disabled = true
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

**Test**

```js
function clickUntilDisabled(selector, callback, pageNo = 0) {
  if (pageNo === 100) {
    throw 'Too many clicks'                      
  }
  cy.get(selector).then($clickable => {
    if ($clickable.prop('disabled')) return;       
    $clickable.click()
    callback(pageNo)                                
    clickUntilDisabled(selector, callback, ++pageNo) 
  })
}

clickUntilDisabled('button', (pageNo) => {
  console.log('Callback pageNo', pageNo)
  cy.get('button')
    .then($button => {
      const assertion = pageNo < 3 ? 'not.be.disabled' : 'be.disabled';
      cy.wrap($button).should(assertion)                                  // passes
    })
  cy.contains('p', `Page no: ${pageNo}`)                                  // passes
})
```

**Log**

```
Click handler nextpage 0
Callback pageNo 0
Click handler nextpage 1
Callback pageNo 1
Click handler nextpage 2
Callback pageNo 2
Click handler nextpage 3
Callback pageNo 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jquery enabled selector](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/#enabled) to check whether the button is enabled or not and based on that perform other actions.

```
cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
    if ($btn.is(":enabled")) {
        cy.wrap($btn).click() //Button is enabled
    } else {
        //Button is disabled
    }
})
```

Comment: Okay, this sounds promising.
Let me try this

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, let me know if there is an alternative way in doing so

```
    cy.get('ul[id=myPager] > li').children('a[class^=page_link]').then(function(pages)
    {
        cy.log(pages.length)
        
        //clicking next until no succeeding pages available to click
        for(var x = 1; x < pages.length; x++)
        {
            cy.get('li').children('a[class=next_link]').click()
            if(x === 2)
            {
                cy.log('No succeeding pages to be clicked')
            }
            else
            {
                cy.log('Clicking')
            }
        }
    })
```

For automating the previous pages just reverse the loop:

```
for(var x=pages.length; x >= 1; x--)
//instructions to follow
```